# How to bind a MudIcon string to Mud Icon component

Tags: icons, mudblazor

```
<MudIcon Icon="@inboxIcon" Color="Color.Primary" />
```

```
@code{

   // here this Icon string is coming from database
   
private string inboxIcon = "Icons.Material.Filled.Inbox"; 

}
```

the above code is is not displaying any icon. How to bind this Icon string?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Old question, but I was also trying to save/load menu icons from the database, and wound up using reflection like the sample below. All the icons I wanted to use were in Icons.Material.Outlined, so I'm just saving the icon name "Person", "Dashboard", etc. (Along with Path and Caption) to load at runtime. This sample might get you going:

```
@using System.Reflection

<MudNavMenu>
    @foreach (var menuitem in MenuItems)
    {
        <MudNavLink Href="@menuitem" Icon="@GetIconValue(Icons.Material.Outlined, @menuitem)">@menuitem</MudNavLink>
    }
</MudNavMenu>

@code {
    string[] MenuItems = new string[] {"Dashboard", "Person"};

    public static string GetIconValue(object SourceField, string IconName)
    {
        return SourceField.GetType().GetProperty(IconName).GetValue(SourceField, null).ToString();
    }
}
```

Run on Mudblazor: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cuQQuplkqVtQpJKV

Comment: Great idea but the MudBlazor sample doesn't work. @user14627004's does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76891986/109941

Answer (score 5):

You are nearly there. Try it like this:

```
<MudIcon Icon="@inboxIcon" Color="Color.Primary" />


@code{

   // here this Icon string is coming from database
   
private string inboxIcon = MudBlazor.Icons.Material.Filled.Inbox; 

}
```

The `Icons` in the namespace will be automatically converted into a string.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding to my question. But, in my case the Mud Icon string is coming from database field as string. I tried using Font awesome and Bootstrap icons as string and they are working.

Comment: But, as you can see, in case of MudIcons the is no string used. An easy solution for you would be to make a switch case and depending an the value coming from db choosing the mudblazor icon in the right format.

Answer (score 3):

This code didn't run "...is a type, which is not valid in the given context"
First you need to create an Object with that type like this:
`private static Icons.Material.Filled iconClass = new Icons.Material.Filled();`

and your function should be like this to get a field:

```
protected static string GetIconValue(object SourceField, string IconName)
{        
    string? teste = SourceField?.GetType()?.GetField(IconName)?.GetValue(null)?.ToString();        
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(teste))
    {
        return @Icons.Material.Filled.Assignment;
    }
    return teste;
}
```